# Limit Boost to First n Matches

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking for a way to guarantee a maximum number of the returned documents match some query.

For example if a user is looking for soup cook books and my query returns the first 10 soup cook books with the highest query score, I want to include at most 2 cook books that are on the top cook book list even if they are not the highest scoring cook books based on my query. The issue here is that if I boost top cook books I will return top cook books only and not necessarily soup cook books which is what the user was looking for.

The only solution I see here is to write two queries but I am hoping there is a way I can accomplish this via either two queries whose results can be merged and have their own limits or some kind of "boost first n matches" type of functionality

Comment: Can you share some example data and queries that you've tried?

Comment: I have not tried anything as I dont even know how to go about solving this issue. This is more of any thoughts on how to accomplish this more than exact code. My thoughts based on my research are in the last paragraph in my question.

Comment: I believe going with 2 queries is the way. You may consider [multi search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) if you want to do two queries at the same time. Please try the two queries approach and tell us if there will still be problems.